# Can relativistic mass increase be used to increase propulsion momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, observers, rocket-science, propulsion

If the propellant used in a rockets is accelerated to near relativistic speed before being ejected from a space craft (accelerating the propellant molecules in a loop before releasing them), can the relativistic increase in mass be used to increase the momentum of the propellant leaving the rocket and thereby accomplish large thrust with small masses?

Comment: Quarks do just that for you by "moving" with relativistic velocity inside of protons and neutrons... if you absolutely insist on piling a really poor semi-classical model of the innards of nucleon on top of a really poor understanding of mass-energy. The short answer to your question is therefor "No, one can not gain anything that way because the mass-energy is either there or it isn't and one can't get it out of nowhere.". Maybe somebody will give you a more formal argument.

Answer (score 1):

Although "relativistic mass" isn't really regarded as a useful concept, you can indeed get an arbitrarily large kick from an arbitrarily small propellant mass, simply by expending more energy to increase the momentum of the propellant. This is already clear in Newtonian mechanics, where $p=\sqrt{2m E}$ with $p$, $m$, and $E$ being the propellant momentum, mass, and kinetic energy, respectively. Relativistically this becomes $p=\sqrt{(m+E)^2-m^2}$ (if $c=1$), which of course reduces to the Newtonian expression when $E\ll m$.

So the main impact of relativity is that eventually the Newtonian $p\propto E^{1/2}$ scaling transitions into a more favorable $p\propto E$ scaling, once the energy you are injecting into the propellant exceeds its rest mass. Note that at this point, the propellant mass becomes irrelevant, and you could just as well accelerate your spacecraft by shining a beam of light.